# Ruler-and-Compass metric: draw a line from any point to separate the area of a triangle?

Tags: geometric-construction

Given a triangle $ABC$ and a point $X$, is it possible to only use Ruler and Compass, to draw a line $l$ through $X$, such that $l$ will split $ABC$ to two parts with equal area?

[image]

Comment: Can $X$ be anywhere in the plane of the triangle, or must $X$ lie within $ABC$?

Comment: @EdwardPorcella anywhere...

Comment: I think a median does the job and unless x lies on it, perhaps.